# Hazelcast QueueStore memory limit property is not working

Tags: queue, hazelcast

Using 3.4.1
I want to limit the number of entry in queue memory and thats why tried setting the memory limit property for queue store config but its not working. I think its not related if we set the property or not, still we will have all the entry stored in both in queue memory and Queuestore.

Find the code: https://gist.github.com/hitendrapratap/f8d27777f264c0966a39

Answer (score 0):

Is the bounded queue what you are looking for: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#bounded-queue ?

Comment: I am trying to implement QueueStore persistence and I was trying to understand how memory limit property for queue store works.